# How do I save and load a JSONObject Collection to/from a file?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit, json

I am currently trying to save a collection of JSONObjects to my .yml file.
But I am stuck at one point when it gets to load the JSONObjects from the file.

My sources:

```
static boolean saveChest(JSONObject obj){
    chestList.add(obj);
    FC = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(STORAGE);
    FC.set("chests", chestList.toArray().toString());
    try {
        FC.save(STORAGE);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean loadChests(){
    try{
        chestList.clear();
        if(!STORAGE.exists()){
            STORAGE.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            STORAGE.createNewFile();
        }
        FC = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(STORAGE);
        Collection<JSONObject> list = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
        list.addAll((Collection<? extends JSONObject>) (JSONObject) FC.get("chests"));
        for(JSONObject temp : list){
            chestList.add(temp);
            Location loc =  (Location) temp.get("loc");
            Hologram holo = HologramsAPI.createHologram(PLUGIN, loc.add(0.5, 2, 0.5));
            holo.appendTextLine("§e§lVote Chest");
            holo.appendTextLine("§bRight-Click with Vote Key to open!");
        }
        return true;
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

public static boolean registerChest(Block chest, ChestType type){
    JSONObject temp = new JSONObject();
    switch(type){
    case VOTE:
        temp.put("loc", chest.getLocation().toString());
        temp.put("type", type.toString());
        Hologram holo = HologramsAPI.createHologram(PLUGIN, chest.getLocation().add(0.5, 2, 0.5));
        holo.appendTextLine("§e§lVote Chest");
        holo.appendTextLine("§bRight-Click with Vote Key to open!");
        break;
    }
    saveChest(temp);
    return false;
}
```

I am getting the following error:

[hastebin of my error](http://hastebin.com/qisebavuxi.avrasm)

Chest.java:245:

```
list.addAll((Collection<? extends JSONObject>) (JSONObject) FC.get("chests"));
```

Trying now for nearly 2 hours to fix that but I assume I just don't get what I have to do to fix it.
Could you help me maybe?

Comment: It seems your JSON is not valid. So it can't be casted to JSONObject. Can you get your FC.get("chests") and check if it is valid or not?!

Comment: In case your JSON is valid, can you do like: JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(FC.get("chests"));

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to cast a collection of Strings (returned from your YamlConfiguration object) directly to a collection of JSONObjects. If the Strings in question are in JSON format, you can instantiate a new JSONParser and parse each String into a JSONObject; e.g.:

```
Collection<JSONObject> list = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
for (String s : FC.get("chests")) {
    list.add((JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(s));
}
```

Or, in order to use addAll(), you could instead first create a Collection of Strings, and then parse them into JSONObjects while looping through the Collection.